# The space of sequences of integers, and an analog of topological space for classes?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Is the collection of integer sequences a set or a class? If it's not a set, then is there an analog of topological spaces for classes? Thank you!

Comment: the set of all the integers $\mathbb Z$ exists then the set of all the integer sequences exists.

Comment: Wrong. There aren't even countably many strings of 0s and 1s.

Comment: There are uncountably many such sequences. If you have a list of sequences $s_1,s_2,...$ you can construct a sequences which is different from $s_1$ at the first value, different from $s_2$ at the second, and so on. Then you get a sequence which is not in this list, contradicting that this list is exhaustive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about sequences of elements of $\Bbb N$ indexed by $\Bbb N$, then the answer is yes. A sequence is merely a function from the index set to the codomain.

This set is actually $\Bbb{N^N}$.

In fact, if $I$ is any set and you want to talk about sequences indexed by $I$, then $\Bbb N^I$ is that set of sequences. Or more generally $A^I$ for a set $A$.

To see that this is a set, note that $f\colon I\to A$ is a subset of $I\times A$. As both $I$ and $A$ are sets, so is $I\times A$. Therefore $A^I$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(I\times A)$.

Comment: Or if you like, you can of course generalize this to the collection of all functions between two given sets.

Comment: @dfeuer: Which is what I point out. Sequences are just functions.

Answer (score 2):

The collection of all sequences of integers is the collection of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$.

Each such function is a subset of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb Z$.

Thus the collection of all of them is a subset of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N\times \Bbb Z)$, and thus a set.

Think about what an analogue of topologies for classes would have to look like, and whether that could make sense.